# ElasticSeach - Get both incomplete and plural words

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I have a product catalog which I am indexing in ElasticSearch using the Elastica client.

While implementing search, I was appending `*` after the typed search terms so that when one types `whis` or `whisk` he will already start seeing search results for `whisky`.

But I want to show results for `poster` when one types `posters` as well.

I was able to achieve the plural to singular result using `snowball` filter. But for that to work, I have to remove `*`.

This is bad because there are no results to show until a full word is entered.

Any ideas how I can go about this? My analyzer code: (taken from [here](http://elastica.io/getting-started/storing-and-indexing-documents.html))

```
'analysis' => array(
    'analyzer' => array(
        'indexAnalyzer' => array(
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
            'filter' => array('lowercase', 'mySnowball')
        ),
        'searchAnalyzer' => array(
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
            'filter' => array('lowercase', 'mySnowball')
        )
    ),
    'filter' => array(
        'mySnowball' => array(
            'type' => 'snowball',
            'language' => 'English'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Bump! Anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with custom functionality.

I search with the exact search phrase without `*`. My code looks for result count. If it's an incomplete word, it will probably return a null result. So I append a `*` to the result query and do another search.

This makes my auto-suggest results slower, but functional.